# UDP Client/Server TypeError

Tags: python

I have a problem with my UDP Client when attempting to run it.

Here is my current code:

```
import socket
UDP_IP_ADDRESS = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT_NO = 6789

thesock.socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
thesock.sendto(UDP_IP_ADDRESS, UDP_PORT)
```

When I run the program, I get an error in the terminal:

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: Try setting `UDP_IP_ADDRESS` to `b"127.0.0.1"` instead (i.e. a bytestring instead of a utf8 string), and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to `sendto()` are the data to send followed by the address. The address can be a tuple containing an IP address and port.

You're missing the data, and instead you've put the IP and port as separate arguments.

So it should be:

```
thesock.sendto(b"Data to send", (UDP_IP_ADDRESS, UDP_PORT))
```